# Is it problematic for a react-redux app that use JWTs to store some of the JWT's payload in redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, jwt

Debating whether it's better to keep the JWT as the sole source of truth even for static values like user id and user permissions that could be instead be stored in state on app initialization or sign in. Is the convenience of seeing that information in redux devtools outweighed by potential issues arising from duplicate sources of data?